# I am curious if I should install these dependencies when I cd into react project or before?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, portfolio

```sh
npm i @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons react-router-dom react-vertical-timeline-component
```

When I install these for my portfolio I should cd into the project first right? I got this from a YouTube video and it didn't specify.

Because last time I did I was getting an error. Below is the error I received.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: personal-portfolio@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: Is your question about which directory to be in or is it about resolving dependency errors?

Comment: When you install dependencies, you need to be in the react project folder, not the parent repository folder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to go to your project's directory(folder). What can help you is, when ever you want to install something check where the `package.json` file is located then `npm i <packages>` there, most of the cases it is located in the root of your project.\

Comment: I edited the question above with the errors I was receiving and from what I googled I cant find much.